# Find all integers that multiplied gives X?

Tags: perl

If I have a number, let's say 12, how can I calculate all integers that multiplied will give 12?

Example: If 12, then the solution would be 1x12, 2x6, 3x4.

How would that be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Christian's Works for a brute force method, to be more elegant try to implement some [integer factorization algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization).

EDIT:

After digging though CPAN (you always should) I found [`Math::Factor::XS`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math%3a%3aFactor%3a%3aXS), here is an example (also I mocked up a pure Perl example using grep/map):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.0;

use Math::Factor::XS qw/factors matches/;

my $num = 12;

say "Factors:";
my @factors = factors $num;
say for @factors;

say "Matches:";
say $_->[0] . "x" . $_->[1] for ( [ 1, $num ] , matches($num, \@factors));

# using grep 
say "Grep:";
my @grep_factors = map { [ $_ , $num / $_ ] } grep { !($num % $_) } (1 .. int sqrt $num);
say $_->[0] . "x" . $_->[1] for @grep_factors;
```

Answer (score 5):

Check from 1 to `sqrt(x)` for divisors. Use those and their pairs. Watch out for squares.